# How can I install a python 2.7 package via reticulate?

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I want to install [undaqTools](https://pythonhosted.org/undaqTools/install.html) via `reticulate`.

Following the instructions, running `easy_install -U undaqTools` in terminal successfully installs the package. But `reticulate::py_install(packages = "undaqTools")` in `R` does not work. Following is what I get:

```
+ "C:/Users/umair/anaconda3/condabin/conda.bat" "install" "--yes" "--prefix" "C:/Users/umair/anaconda3/envs/undaq" "-c" "conda-forge" "undaqTools"
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - undaqtools

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.


Error: one or more Python packages failed to install [error code 1]
```

Comment: it looks like `py_install` simply tries to use `conda` to install the package

Comment: This worked for me: `py_install(packages = "undaqTools", pip = TRUE)`